# Disable Close Button without Disabling Icon

Tags: vb.net, controlbox

my problem is so simple but I can't seem to get it solved.

I just want to remove the Close Button from my form and don't remove the icon.

I used ControlBox = false but it removes the form's icon as well, I just want to keep it.

Is there anyway I can do it either by code or properties?

Comment: You might find your answer [Here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1743493/3332258)

Answer (score 1):

Add it under `Public Class Form ...` :

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim Param As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        Param.ClassStyle = Param.ClassStyle Or &H200
        Return Param
    End Get
End Property
```

It should work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you want something full of capabilities, then you could use my [SystemMenuManager By Elektro](http://pastebin.com/yexrLiwS) Class.

Just add all the code into a single Class and use it like in the example below:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim SystemMenu As New SystemMenuManager(Me)

    Private Shadows Sub Load() Handles MyBase.Load

        ' Disables the 'Close' button and 'Close' menu-item.
        SystemMenu.SetItemState(SystemMenuManager.Item.Close, 
                                SystemMenuManager.ItemState.Disabled)

    End Sub

End Class
```